# How to install mellanox driver?

Tags: centos7, mellanox

I have nodes with an Infiniband connection and a centos 7.9 installed.

when I execute the following

**# lspci | grep Mellanox**

01:00.0 Network controller: Mellanox Technologies MT27500 Family [ConnectX-3]

**# lspci -vv -s 01:00.0 | grep "Part number" -A 3**

[PN] Part number: MCX353A-FCB

I will reinstall the system to rockylinux.

My question is: how to install the Mellanox hardware

Is it enough to use the provided package from the distribution (yum group install Infiniband) or should I also use the package provided by the manufacturers in the following link:

https://www.mellanox.com/products/infiniband-drivers/linux/mlnx_ofed

Comment: better luck on https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: thanks, I have re-posted it on unix.stackexchange.com